# asp.net core Razor Pages: want DisplayAttribute Description to display as title/tooltip

Tags: asp.net-core, data-annotations, razor-pages

I have an asp.net core (.Net 5) Razor Pages application.  In my model I have a property decorated like so:

```
    [Display(Name = "Borrower Name", Prompt = "Borrower Name", Description = "Restrict the search results by borrower name.")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string BorrowerName { get; set; }
```

I want the "Description" property set above to render as the input's title (aka tooltip). Here is how I am rendering it. It renders correctly, and the placeholder is correctly set to the Prompt ("Borrower Name"), but my Description does not get rendered to the "title" attribute. What am I missing?

```
<label asp-for="BorrowerName" class="form-label"></label>
<input asp-for="BorrowerName" class="form-control" />
```

Here is what gets rendered:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Borrower Name must be a string with a maximum length of 255." data-val-length-max="255" id="BorrowerName" maxlength="255" name="BorrowerName" placeholder="Borrower Name" value="">
```

The documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.description?view=net-5.0) says "The Description property is typically used as a tooltip or description UI element", but not a clue as to how to make that happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do it manually. As an example:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetDescription<T>(string propertyName) where T: class
    {
        MemberInfo memberInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
        if (memberInfo == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return memberInfo.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?.GetDescription();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<input asp-for="BorrowerName" class="form-control" title='@Extensions.GetDescription<YourClass>("BorrowerName")'/>
```

Comment: Slight correction on rendering title:  title='(@Extensions.GetDescription<MyClass>("BorrowerName"))'

Comment: Here is a similar alternative answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70381292/get-displayattribute-prompt-from-asp-net-core-razor-page

Answer (score 2):

One slight adaptation to make it a proper extension method is as follows:

```
  public static class Extensions
  {
    public static string GetDescription<T>(this T _, string propertyName) where T : class
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
      {
        throw new ArgumentException($"'{nameof(propertyName)}' cannot be null or whitespace.", nameof(propertyName));
      }

      MemberInfo memberInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
      if (memberInfo == null)
      {
        return null;
      }

      return memberInfo.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?.GetDescription();
    }
  }
```

Note the inclusion of the "this T _" part to make it an extension method on any class (i.e., model) type via Duck typing and the use of a discard (i.e., the "_" part) as the actual parameter itself is unused (only the type of  is needed).

Usage is then simply:

```
<input asp-for="BorrowerName" class="form-control" title='@Model.GetDescription(nameof(<YourClass>.BorrowerName))' />
```

Hope this helps :)