# Get DisplayAttribute.Prompt from ASP.NET Core Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

Let's assume I have the following model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Display(Prompt = "Hello")]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }     
}
```

How can I get the `Prompt` value from the Razor code (cshtml)? I want to use it as the default selection in a drop-down list.
I had an ASP.NET MVC solution using the property `ModelMetadata.Watermark` but as far as I know, it is not available in ASP.NET Core.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I create a sample code to test and it works for me. You can get the vaule `Prompt` and use it.

[image]

*Sample code*

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
@model dotnetcoreMVC.Prescription;
@using System.Reflection;
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
<div>
    @{
        MemberInfo property = typeof(dotnetcoreMVC.Prescription).GetProperty("PrescriptionText");
        var dd = property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute)) as DisplayAttribute;
        <p>@dd.Prompt</p>
    }
</div>
```

*My Model.*

[image]